# certificate verify failed with MechanicalSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, mechanicalsoup

I want to retrieve some data from my router using MechanicalSoup. However when I try I get "certificate verify failed". As I see it I have two options

1. Find a way to disable SSL verification
2. Tell MechanicalSoup where it can find the pem file (I created it using "openssl s_connect ....")

My code looks like this so far:

```
import argparse
import mechanicalsoup
from getpass import getpass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Get data from router")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--username", help="User", type=str,
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--server", help="server", type=str,
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", help="Port", type=str,
                    required=False, default="8443")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="Verbose output. Add " +
                    "additional v to increase level.",
                    action="count", default=0)
args = parser.parse_args()

args.password = getpass("Password:")

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
    soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
    raise_on_404=True,
    user_agent='getdata.py/0.1',
)

browser.set_verbose(args.verbose)

browser.open("https://" + args.server + ":" + args.port)
```

Full error message from end of stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "perfcreate.py", line 33, in <module>
    browser.open("https://" + args.server + ":" + args.port)
  File "/home/andyw/mypy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mechanicalsoup/stateful_browser.py", line 133, in open
    resp = self.get(url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andyw/mypy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mechanicalsoup/browser.py", line 124, in get
    response = self.session.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andyw/mypy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andyw/mypy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/andyw/mypy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andyw/mypy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.1', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use: `browser.open("https://" + args.server + ":" + args.port, verify=False)`

Comment: GAH! I had tried that before and it didn't work. Just tried it again and now it does. Guess I had a typo somewhere. Just as an extra reference for others:
verify="certfile" works as well.

Answer (score 0):

MechanicalSoup doesn't do anything specific with SSL certificates, but `browser.open` forwards its arguments to [requests.Session.request](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/api/#requests.Session.request)'s constructor, which exposes among others:

> **verify** – (optional) Either a boolean, in which case it controls whether we verify the server’s TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it must be a path to a CA bundle to use. Defaults to True.
>
> **cert** – (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, (‘cert’, ‘key’) pair.

So, you may use `verify=False` as the other answer suggests (unsafe), or [download the certificate from the website](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website) and use `cert="/path/to/certificate.pem`.